# Remove a string if it ends within java

Tags: java, regex

I have to remove "OR" if it ends with in a given string.

```
public class StringReplaceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "SELECT count OR %' OR";
        System.out.println("matches:" + text.matches("OR$"));

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("OR$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found match at: " + matcher.start() + " to " + matcher.end());
            System.out.println("substring:" + text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
            text = text.replace(text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()), "");
            System.out.println("after replace:" + text);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
matches:false
Found match at: 19 to 21
substring:OR
after replace:SELECT count  %'
```

Its removing all the occurrences of the string "OR"  but I have to remove if its ends with only.
How to do that ?

Also regex is working with Pattern but not working with String.matches().
What is the difference between both and what is the best way to remove a string if it ends with ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text.matches(".*OR$")` as the match goes over the entire string.
Or:

```
if (text.endsWith("OR"))
```

Or:

```
text = text.replaceFirst(" OR$", "");
```

Comment: text = text.replaceFirst(" OR$", ""); its solved my thing. Thanks @joop-eggen

Answer (score 2):

If you need to just remove the last OR, then I suggest using `substring` method as it is faster than a full regex pattern. In that case, you can remove the OR using this code:

```
text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("OR"));
```

If you need to replace OR by something else, you will need to use this code which detects the last OR with a break in the string.

```
text.replaceFirst("\\bOR$", "SOME");
```